# How can i send the declaration type as parameter

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class BaseItem it have addToDb() method, class Car and class Driver both of Car and Driver are based on "BaseItem".

class CarEditor and class DriverEditor are based on QWidget, both of them have an additional method BaseItem* getData().

class "TheEditor" is based on QWidget It has QStackWidget,
page_1 has QLineEdit (to search) & QListWidget,
page_2 is a QWidget (which one from editors should be their).

Also All Widget based classes were made using qdesigner.

The problem is when i send "QWidget *editor" as QWidget to TheEditor as parameter, i don't get access to getData() method because it's not in QWidget also i can't cast it because i don't know whether it was CarEditor or DriverEditor or other

How can i put CarEditor or DriverEditor or other similar to them in page two and use getData() method?

Knowing that the only thing i will do after getting BaseItem* from add() method is calling it.

Comment: It will easier to understand your question if you post code. You're trying to explain your code here and I don't really get your question.

Comment: Use _Polymorphic_  virtual methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most apparent solution I think would be to create a `BaseEditor` `QWidget`-derived class with a `BaseItem *getData()` virtual method. Then `CarEditor` and `DriverEditor` inherit from that and override `getData()`, and `TheEditor` works with instances of `BaseEditor` instead of the generic `QWidget`. The `BaseEditor`s could be `qobject_cast()` to the actual type if necessary.

`BaseEditor` class could be very simple:

```cpp
#include <QWidget>
class BaseItem;

class BaseEditor : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    using QWidget::QWidget;  // use base class constructors

    virtual BaseItem *getData() const { return nullptr; }
};
```

And for example `CarEditor`:

```cpp
#include "BaseEditor.h"
#include "Car.h"

class CarEditor: public BaseEditor
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    using BaseEditor::BaseEditor;

    BaseItem *getData() const override { return m_car; }

  private:
    Car *m_car = nullptr;  // presumably this would get set somehow to !null :)
};
```

**ADDED**: To use your custom `BaseEditor` as a base class for existing `CarEditor` and `DriverEditor` in QtDesigner (instead of `QWidget`) an extra step may be required. Although it is simple to [add a custom widget to an existing form](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405227&seqNum=3) (using the first method described), there is no way I know of to change the base type once the .ui form has been created.

But you can do it manually by editing the form's `.ui` file XML directly. First close the file in QtDesigner/Creator.  Then open it in a plain-text editor (eg. r-click on file in Creator project tree and select Open With -> Plain Text Editor).

At the top will be something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>CarEditor</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="CarEditor">
...
 </widget>
 ...
</ui>
```

Edit it to change the base class name and add `customwidget` details:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>CarEditor</class>
 <widget class="BaseEditor" name="CarEditor">
...
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>BaseEditor</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>BaseEditor.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 ...
</ui>
```

Save, and once reopened in QtDesigner it should show up with the proper base class.  Note that as described in the *Informit* article this will not reflect any custom properties of the `BaseEditor`, but it will let you edit the design as if it was a plain `QWidget`.

Comment: Can i promote qwidget to baseeditor instead of modifying the .ui file?

Comment: @Ayaan If you mean the base (top-level) item class in Designer, then no, as I said I don't know of any other way. If you mean another widget within the top-level widget, then yes you do that through the Designer UI as described in that article. So for example if you want to insert an instance of `BaseEditor` (or `Car/DriverEditor` into `TheEditor` then you could do that by promoting using the Designer UI.  But to change `CarEditor` itself from `QWidget` to `BaseEditor`, the XML needs to be edited directly.  I hope that is clear...  :)

Comment: i didn't understand the part of customwidget why i will add custom widget to careditor,i applied all above but instead of customwidget in careditor i made a promote to a widget in TheEditor, CarEditor doesn't show also it doesn't appear at all

Comment: @Ayaan I'm not really sure what you're asking. For it to work as I described the UI form for `CarEditor` needs to have the base class of `BaseEditor` in the XML as I described. Then open it in Designer to make sure the base class is correct and the `#include` for `BaseEditor.h` is found correctly. After that the promotion in `TheEditor` should work, assuming it can find the `#include` file for `CarEditor.h`. If that doesn't answer the question or doesn't work, you'll need to post some code to examine.

Comment: you can forget all above, when you use "using BaseEditor::BaseEditor;" it won't call "ui->setupUi(this);"

Comment: Right, if you want BaseEditor itself to have UI elements then using the default c'tor could never work since the UI would never be set up anywhere. My example was minimal for what you were asking, but it does make sense that you'd want common UI elements in BaseEditor vs. repeating them in the Car/Driver editors.

Comment: so you suggest to drop using UI file and write it in code, isn't it? may i have your email !